# display Applet on top of Google Map

Tags: java, google-maps, jar, applet, overlay

Can I display a java applet on top of a google map using a custom overlay so that it scrolls along when I scroll the map?

Comment: What do you want to show on top of what? The applet on top of the map?

Comment: The map is no different from any other html element then, I'd think. You don't need to do anything specific, unless you want to scroll the applet along with the map. Applets *are* somewhat different from ordinary html elements in that they are not transparent and always rectangular.

Comment: With ["Custom Overlay"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays) I can easily add an image and when I drag the map, the image - overlay stays in the same place it was created. I want to replace the image with an applet. If I simply change the path and instead of the image try to view the applet the result is just an empty box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the applet should stay in place when the map is scrolled, you don't need to do anything particularly special, and it isn't necessary to create a custom overlay. The map and the applet can be two different `<div>` elements that sit in the same parent and are positioned such that the applet is drawn on top of the map. It's no different from positioning any other html element.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/7Ckhu/

If you want to add the applet in a custom overlay, for example because you want it to scroll/drag along with the map, you can programmatically create a `div` element containing the applet

```
var appletDiv = document.createElement('div');
var objectElement = document.createElement('object');
objectElement.setAttribute('type', 'application/x-java-applet');
objectElement.setAttribute('height', '200');
objectElement.setAttribute('width', '200');
appletDiv.appendChild(objectElement);

var codeParam = document.createElement('param');
codeParam.setAttribute('name', 'code');
codeParam.setAttribute('value', <<the code>>);
objectElement.appendChild(codeParam);
var archiveParam = document.createElement('param');
archiveParam.setAttribute('name', 'archive');
archiveParam.setAttribute('value', <<the archive>>);
objectElement.appendChild(archiveParam);
<< etc etc >>
```

and overlay it on the map using your own custom overlay class or using one of the many implementations available, like the [gmaps div overlay library](http://jonyt.github.com/gmaps-div-overlay/divoverlay.js).

```
var divOverlay = new DivOverlay(appletDiv, map, map.getCenter());
divOverlay.show();
```

[The result](http://jsfiddle.net/4BW68/2/embedded/result/), however, is disappointing.
[(jsfiddle including code)](http://jsfiddle.net/4BW68/2/)

Mozilla doesn't like applets much but if I click the red lego block in the navigation bar and tell it to allow the applet, things look quite nice.

Chrome shows everything, but when I scroll and hit the edge of the map, the applet does not get clipped. It gets drawn outside the map. And at some point the redraw mechanism gets upset. This may be fixeable but at the very least this does not work out of the box.

IE simply draws a white square, no applet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however adding a div with the applet on top of the map is not the best solution for me, since when I am moving the map I would like the applet to move with it.

Comment: So put them in a joint div and move them around together: http://jsfiddle.net/7Ckhu/14/

Comment: The effect I want to create is not the same, check [this](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple). That is an image though. I want to replace it with a .jar applet.

Comment: so you *do* want to scroll it along with the map! got it now

Comment: added example using custom overlay

Comment: Thank you very much for all the information, it has been really helpful!

Comment: Consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer if it is of use ;-) If you do not consider the question answered yet, which part do you think deserves more attention?

Comment: The information you supported me was really good but it is not exactly what I was looking for. As you saw in this [sample](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple) the map and the picture are like one object.
In yours, the divs are two completely different objects (and of course they are) but I want to create the same effect as the sample. Having the applet moving outside the map will do no good. :/

Comment: So please upvote the answer for being good information. I understand if you don't consider the question answered yet, since my answer is basically no, it cannot be done in a universal way. I am, myself, also curious if others can get the applet to clip on all browsers.

Comment: I need more reputation it says.. :/